# How do I customize theme in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I am trying to customize design in magento. Magento version is 1.9.2.0.
[image]

This is my design settings in Magento Admin. Though I can not find any package `rwd` in `magento/skin/frontend`, so i created new package `rwd/trend` but it is not working.

[image]

When I create another package named `ksade/trend`, magento gives me this error. Can somebody help me to sort it out and guide me on how to customize a theme?

**Edit**
Skin/frontend dir
[image]

app/design/frontend dir
[image]

[This is how site design look like](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1654969/efb212c25570f86a1af5b980d5c62d44)

Comment: Add your theme and package name please

Comment: I am not going to use any ready to use theme, I just want to make some HTML,CSS changes in existing package/theme so i just need to override current styles.css which is in `skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css` but the problem is there is no `rwd` package in skins/frontend`.

Comment: Magento provide rwd theme by default.

Comment: @SHPatel: So I've header/read it, but I can not see `rwd` package where it is supposed to be in magento setup. Thank you.

Comment: I there is no rwd then you can create it in skin and design path with package. like rdw/trend.

Answer (score 0):

Magento theme packages are in `app/design/frontend/` directory. You can see the rwd package there.

The css, images and j files are in `skin/frontend/` directory.

In order to customize the theme you need to create a new theme. As a good starting point you can use rwd packge.

Read https://www.flinttechnology.co.uk/customising-rwd-magento-responsive-theme/

Comment: I looked for it and there is no rwd package

Comment: that's strange, can you share some screenshot to see how it looks like?

Comment: I've edited question with other screen shots, please check. Also of styles.css is rendering from path "exaple.com/shop/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css", that's whats more strange.

Comment: Something wrong with this. Either this is not magento 1.9 or someone has removed the rwd theme.

Comment: Try creating the file skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css and add your changes, but not sure whether it will work !

Comment: Ok I'll try and see what happens, Thank you @Nidhessh

Comment: Yes other developer had worked on it before, but even if he had removed `rwd` package, magento is supposed to throw error as `rwd` package has been set in configurations. right?

Comment: Magento has a default theme fallback mechanism. If it doesn't find the files in `rwd/theme/`, it will check in `rwd/default`, then `base/default/`.

Also it will be worth checking whether there is any design exceptions added in **System >> Design** menu

Answer (score 0):

On both app/design/frontend and skin/frontend there is a rwd folder. From there you can modify what you want.

Also check the below links:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/Resources/archive/magento_community_edition_user_guide_v.1.9.pdf

Comment: I looked for it and there is no `rwd` package